# add button in DataTable that includes a script gives me an error -

Tags: json, ajax, laravel, datatable

The button works perfectly, but when trying to list it in DataTable, the plugin does not load

Controller Code:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Siniestro;

class DataTableController extends Controller
{
    public function paraderivar()
    {
        $siniestros = Siniestro::select('id', 'siniestro','fechaip', 'modalidad','direccion','localidad', 'inspector')->get();

        return datatables()->of($siniestros)->toJson();
    }
}
```

DataTable Script

```
    <script>
    
    $('.tablita').DataTable({
        "ajax": "{{route('datatable.paraderivar')}}",
        "select": "true",
        "columns":[
            {data: 'id'},
            {data: 'siniestro'},
            {data: 'fechaip'},
            {data: 'modalidad'},
            {data: 'direccion'},
            {data: 'localidad'},
            {data: 'inspector'},
            
            
            
            
        ]
        
    

        
    });

</script> 

<script>


 $('#addT').hide();
 $('#addButton').hide();
 $('#updateT').show();
 $('#updateButton').show();

$.ajaxSetup({
    headers:{
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
})

//---------------------------------------------- Llamar datos de la BD ---------------------------------------------------------------

    function allData(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "/teacher/all",
        success: function (response){
            var data = ""
            $.each(response, function(key, value){
                data = data + "<tr>"
                data = data + "<td>"+value.id+"</td>"
                data = data + "<td>"+value.siniestro+"</td>"
                data = data + "<td>"+value.fechaip+"</td>"
                data = data + "<td>"+value.modalidad+"</td>"
                data = data + "<td>"+value.direccion+"</td>"
                data = data + "<td>"+value.localidad+"</td>"
                data = data + "<td>"+value.inspector+"</td>"
                data = data + "<td>"
                data = data + "<button class='btn btn-info btn-sm' onclick='editData("+value.id+")'>Asignar</button>"
                
                data = data + "</td>"
                data = data + "</tr>"
            })
            $('tbody').html(data);
        }
    })
}
```

blade-view

[Working perfectly, but without button i need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4R8Y.png)

I just added this portion of code that I had not declared... from here I pass the data to the table.

I don't understand what is causing me a conflict with DataTable... maybe you can help me now

Now the Datables plugin works fine, but when I do a search in the plugin's search box, the "Asignar" button disappears from Acciones column.

[image: View]

Answer (score 0):

So far in your datatable script, I do not see any mention of the column 'action'.

Unless you did:

```
{data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false}
```

The datatable is not even seeing your button column. Also, the imgur link you provided is not loading, it times out.

Comment: I put it at the time, and as I said above, it loaded all the values ​​as "undefined", and obviously, when clicking nothing happened

Comment: @Sr.Miyagui  I also noticed that you put an addition character here: >";`
why do you need ` after ; symbol? It is giving an error in my IDE. Try removing that extra character and update here please. Just curious: what IDE are you using to code?

Comment: Ok, i edit this and other '. I use Visual Studio Code.now, it gives me two errors... "Method Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse::addColumn does not exist" The plugin DataTable is Load but dont show data

Comment: I just noticed. Usually yajra datatables are declared like:
return Datatables::of($campaignlist)->addColumn('action', function ($campaignlist) {

I am not sure what you are trying to do with ->toJson() method in your code but chances are that is not a valid method for the datatable. What plugin for datatable are you using? Do you have this in your controller: use Yajra\DataTables\DataTables; ?

Comment: Yajra\DataTables\DataTables; no, I just added it, but I clarify that the datatables are seen without problems in other views... but this is the only one in which I also have a lot of JS code... I calculate that's why I have this problem, besides that such Maybe I shouldn't include toJson? In that case, I should add the tbody with the foreach, right? I'm not sure how to adapt "Datatables::of($campaignlist)->addColumn('action', function ($campaignlist)" to my code

Comment: Just try removing the toJson and see what the response is, no reason to change foreach or tbody, not sure where you even put those tbh.

Comment: i remove toJson,; now give the error "Yajra\DataTables\DataTableAbstract::rawColumns(): Argument #1 ($columns) must be of type array, string given, called in /home/u277224827/domains/siniestrosdag.com/dash_roles test/app/Http/Controllers/SiniestroController.php on line 364"

Comment: @Mashtan - Your answer does not actually provide a solution to the problem. Please see [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead), which may be relevant here.

Comment: @Sr.Miyagui I am feeling you are not putting the whole code for us to see. you mention $columns variable not being an array. yet I see no example of that variable being used in your code whatsoever. I am afraid this issue in entirely unrelated to datatable itself and is rooted in another portion of the code that you did not share with us.

Comment: @Mashtan i add the code!! help me!

Comment: @Sr.Miyagui You mentioned in your error message:  Argument #1 ($columns) must be of type array, string given.

I see no mention of a variable called $columns in your code yet. I can only assume that $siniestros is just a translation of that and go from there. In that case, are you sure the variable $siniestros is an array? Where exactly is this $columns variable located and what is it's output? Friendly reminder that we have no way to debug what SiniestroController.php is or what is the line no 364. Please try to view this from our perspective.

Comment: @Mashtan 
Sorry for the delay, I was complicated. I was able to work on my code, and the plugin now works, and the button works too, but when I do a search the button disappears; Could you help me with this? I already edited my query with the current state of my code

Comment: @Sr.Miyagui I have edited my answer. Try to use orderable: false, searchable: false for that column. I do not think a button can be used as a search parameter. Do that and see if the issue goes away.

Comment: dude, it's not working. Look that in the first part of my code that I edited I removed the addColumn, since something in the syntax gave me an error; That must be why the system throws me an error with the "action" column if I put the line of code you sent me